# reinflating Viewstub

Tags: android, containers, inflate, viewstub

I have a problem.

I slip my Screen in two areas with 2 ViewStubs.

But if i inflated the ViewStubs they are no more accessible and i can't inflate an other View within this ViewStub.

So what is an alternative to use these kind containers.

Here some Code. You all love Code:

```
    ViewStub contentSpace = (ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.ContentSpace);       
    contentSpace.setLayoutResource(R.layout.view1);
    contentSpace.inflate();
    contentSpace.setInflatedId(R.id.Content);
    RelativeLayout content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Content);

    contentSpace.setLayoutResource(R.layout.view1); //crash
    contentSpace.inflate();
```

Comment: could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342121/inflate-a-view-layout-into-another-layout/5343733#5343733

Answer (score 2):

It seems like `ViewStub` can't be re-inflated. It is designed to be inflated just once, then it is removed from the View hierarchy. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11579271/752781

Answer (score -1):

Here my Solution

rootLayout is a linear Layout where may ViewStubs were located.

```
    rootLayout.removeView(contentLayout);
    inflater.inflate(R.id.view1, rootLayout);
    contentLayout = findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);
```

view1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"    
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout">
[...]
```