# layoutinflater doesn't inflate the full layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I tried to inflate this  [constrains layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C891I.png) into another constrains layout.

but when I run it i got only get the [pink card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osgOi.png) the four ImageView doesn't appear inside the card .

here is the main XML file which I need to inflate another layout inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/wall"
tools:context=".StepThreeActivity">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="635dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:padding="13dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/forward" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is java class related to the previous main XML

```
public class StepThreeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step_three);

    initialization();
    characterInitialization();


    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      inflater.inflate(R.layout.card1,
              constraintLayout, true);  
}
```

here is card1.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2c"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="347dp"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:backgroundTint="#FBD5D8"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:padding="13dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: And what should be there?

Comment: four image view

Comment: Can you show all related codes? Your layouts and whole your fragments and activities

Comment: ok, I updated my question

Comment: Did you saw this topic https://stackoverflow.com/a/5343733/11538132?

Also is this 
`inflater.inflate(R.layout.card1,constraintLayout,constraintLayout, true);`
the correct code?
I can't find inflater.inflate in docs with 4 parameters.
Also I can't see in your code what exactly this constraintLayout is

Comment: sorry it was by mistake, I just have one constraintLayout which its id is constraintLayout2 from the main xml, I didn't post the initialization.

Comment: Can you post  your whole project on github or somewhere else?

Comment: here it is https://github.com/rana1m/Abjadity
check StepThreeActivity.java, activity_step_three.xml and card1.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that the 4 card images don't appear because you actually didn't add them to the layout.

snippets from card1.xml:

```
tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a1"
tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a2"
tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a3"
tools:srcCompat="@mipmap/a4"
```

When you use `tools` name space you are affecting the layout only in the android studio Layout Validation pane, and that won't affect it when you run your app.

For more info about `tools` namesapce, you can have a look at [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes).

To fix this you need to replace `tools` with `app` name space. So your card1.xml layout will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2c"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="347dp"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:backgroundTint="#FBD5D8"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:padding="13dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="111dp"
        android:layout_height="149dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/a1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="106dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="168dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/a2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/a3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="153dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="172dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/a4" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to inflate layout in this way?

Can't you just include this layout

```
<include layout="@layout/card1 ... />
```

whole xml file:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="635dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
    android:elevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    android:padding="13dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <include layout="@layout/card1 ... />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/back" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/forward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/forward" />
     </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I need to inflate different layout for specific button, EX: the user click button one I will inflate card 1.xml, the user click button tow I will inflate card2.xml. have another Idea?